# Set Initial view controller with tab bar and nav bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller as my initial view controller in storyboard (with the arrow). However when a user signs in the first time, I'm trying to change the initial view controller programmatically in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to start out at a navigation controller to go through a couple VCs for them to enter signup information (I don't want a tab bar for this). Although I'm changing the initial VC in my app delegate, I'm getting a crash with `Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1031374f8) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1031374a8).` I was under the impression that the initial VC would be changed and not reference the Tab Bar Controller at all? Is there a way I can accomplish changing the initial VC without the Tab Bar Controller being referenced? Here is my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, any help is GREATLY appreciated!

```
  if User.current() == nil {
     let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let navigationControllerr:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
     let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplashPageVC")
     navigationControllerr.viewControllers = [initialViewController]
     self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControllerr
  }
```

Comment: just use a simple check in appDelegate that if value of login info is not nil navigate to tabbar else navigate to sign in Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try something like this.

```
if User.current() == nil {
     let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplashPageVC")
     let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
     self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControllerr
  }
```